# Play - using the paginate and table module together

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I tried using the paginate and the table modules together in an app but the list is not diplaying correctly.
I am using play 1.2.5 .
here is what i did:-

The users model:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.*;

@Entity
public class users extends Model {

    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String username;

    public users(String email, String password, String username) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

The controller:

```
package controllers;
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import java.util.*; 
import play.modules.paginate.ModelPaginator; 
import models.*;
```

public class Application extends Controller {
    public static void index() {
    ModelPaginator paginator = new ModelPaginator(users.class);
      render(paginator);
    }
}

The view:

```
 #{paginate.list items : paginator, as 'r'}  
 #{table r/}  
 #{/paginate.list}
```

Did this but did not work well

so what is wrong?

Comment: I didn't downvoted you, however I think that you should try describe little bit more your question, ie, what did you try. Give some samples etc. your question is very localized.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use both together: First you paginate: you get a sublist of the whole list, with which you then construct the pretty table using the table module.